# How to edit a voice and audio message in a telegram with robot?

Tags: php, json, telegram, telegram-bot

How to edit a voice and audio message in a telegram with robot?
Text messaging is easy to edit, but audio messages are not edited

```
$update = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$message_id = $update->message->message_id;
$chat_id = $update->message->chat->id;
$text = "New Massage";
var_dump(
            makeHTTPRequest('editMessageText', [
                'parse_mode' => 'HTML',
                'disable_web_page_preview' => true,
                'chat_id' => $chat_id,
                'message_id' => $message_id ,
                'text' => $text,
                'reply_markup' => json_encode([
                    'inline_keyboard' => [
                        [
                            ['text' => " 0", 'callback_data' => "F"],
                            ['text' => " 0", 'callback_data' => "S"],
                            ['text' => " 0", 'callback_data' => "D"],
                        ]
                    ]
                ])
            ])
        );
```

Answer (score -1):

Media messages can have only their caption (editMessageCaption) and reply markup (editMessageReplyMarkup) edited.